# How might one "git describe" every commit?

Tags: git

For instance, something like this:

```
$ git describe --all
v0-5-g654178b
v0-4-gf7127a0
v0-3-gbb3ab93
v0-2-gf193081
v0-1-g892d3ad
v0
```

Or this:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --describe
v0-5-g654178b (HEAD, master) improved documentation
v0-4-gf7127a0 Senseless commit to trigger ci build
v0-3-gbb3ab93 fixed the fix
v0-2-gf193081 refactored nertz
v0-1-g892d3ad WIP first foray into i18n
v0 (tag: v0, origin/master) Initial commit
```

Wouldn't that be cool?

Comment: Adam, if you do not have merges, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/17379010/427545 for a command to include `git describe`. I think we have the very same question, but I am not looking for just a single line, but for tags inside the full `git log` output.

Answer (score 3):

This feature does not currently exist in mainline git. You could roll your own (using `git rev-list` with `git describe` and `git log`), and/or submit a patch to the git project.