# How can I decorate a git log with its nearest tag?

Tags: git

`git log --decorate` adds information about related refs to the log output:

```
commit 9e895ace5d82df8929b16f58e9f515f6d54ab82d (tag: v3.10-rc7)
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Sat Jun 22 09:47:31 2013 -1000

    Linux 3.10-rc7
```

This information helps tracking which tag (or branch) contains this commit. When viewing a restricted set of files (say, a subdirectory), there does not have to be a tag for those commits. Is there a way to put a reference to a tag in the log output?

I previously mentioned `git describe`, but that yields `v3.10-rc7-135-g98b6ed0` which is relative to a tag of branch where this change was committed. What I am looking for is a tag name between commits.

For clarity, this is the current situation:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline
98b6ed0 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net
1a506e4 Merge branch 'drm-fixes' of git://people.freedesktop.org/~airlied/linux
578a131 dlci: validate the net device in dlci_del()
11eb264 dlci: acquire rtnl_lock before calling __dev_get_by_name()
...
9e895ac (tag: v3.10-rc7) Linux 3.10-rc7
```

What I want to have is something like:

```
98b6ed0 (v3.10-rc7+, HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net
1a506e4 (v3.10-rc7+) Merge branch 'drm-fixes' of git://people.freedesktop.org/~airlied/linux
578a131 (v3.10-rc7+) dlci: validate the net device in dlci_del()
11eb264 (v3.10-rc7+) dlci: acquire rtnl_lock before calling __dev_get_by_name()
...
9e895ac (tag: v3.10-rc7) Linux 3.10-rc7
```

Using `git describe`'s output instead of the commit hash would show something like:

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline -n4 | awk '{system("git describe " $1 " |tr -d '\''\n'\''");$1="";print}'
v3.10-rc7-135-g98b6ed0 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net
v3.10-rc7-54-g1a506e4 Merge branch 'drm-fixes' of git://people.freedesktop.org/~airlied/linux
v3.10-rc6-81-g578a131 dlci: validate the net device in dlci_del()
v3.10-rc6-80-g11eb264 dlci: acquire rtnl_lock before calling __dev_get_by_name()
...
v3.10-rc7 (tag: v3.10-rc7) Linux 3.10-rc7
```

As you can see, older tag names are used as reference point rather than the point where the commit got merged. For illustation purposes, I am using `git log --oneline` here, but I actually want to use fuller output, e.g. `git log -p --stat`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--first-parent` parameter of `git describe` (introduced with git 1.8.4) shows where a commit is *derived from*. In order to see a relation to the *first tag following the commit*, use `git describe --contains`. This options gets very slow (~6 seconds) when you delve deeper in the history though. Available since git 1.5.3.

The command `git name-rev` can be used to annotate `git rev-name` and works
with `--graph` and `--color` too! From its manual page:

> Given a commit, find out where it is relative to the local refs. Say somebody
>   wrote you about that fantastic commit
>   33db5f4d9027a10e477ccf054b2c1ab94f74c85a. Of course, you look into the commit,
>   but that only tells you what happened, but not the context.
>
> Enter `git name-rev`:
>
> ```
> % git name-rev 33db5f4d9027a10e477ccf054b2c1ab94f74c85a
> 33db5f4d9027a10e477ccf054b2c1ab94f74c85a tags/v0.99~940
> ```
>
> Now you are wiser, because you know that it happened 940 revisions before v0.99.
>
> Another nice thing you can do is:
>
> ```
> % git log | git name-rev --stdin
> ```

This last command appends something to every 40-character SHA-1 hash as shown below (the highlighted part is added by `git name-rev`).

```
commit 1ee2dcc2245340cf4ac94b99c4d00efbeba61824 (tags/v3.13-rc1~33)
Merge: 4457e6f 091e066
Author: Linus Torvalds

    Merge git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net

commit b4089d6d8e71a7293e2192025dfa507a04f661c4 (tags/v3.13-rc1~7^2~6^2^2~8)
Author: Felix Fietkau

    rt2x00: fix a crash bug in the HT descriptor handling fix
...
commit dfb6b7c109a7f98d324a759599d1b4616f02c79f (tags/v3.12-rc7~20^2~20^2^2~11)
Author: Stanislaw Gruszka
Date:   Mon Sep 23 04:08:13 2013 +0200

    Revert "rt2x00pci: Use PCI MSIs whenever possible"

    This reverts commit 9483f40d8d01918b399b4e24d0c1111db0afffeb (tags/v3.11-rc1~16^2~103^2^2~111).
```

---

An awk script for post-processing `git log` output is available at https://git.lekensteyn.nl/scripts/tree/git-log-describe.awk
(written before I knew of `git rev-name`). Features:

- Considers the hash from `commit <hash>` instead of 40-character hashes (works with `--abbrev-commit` too).
- Support for `git log --graph` format.
- Adds `git describe --contains` or `git describe --first-parent` output.
- Possibility to specify a cache directory to save time later.

Comment: Sounds great, more precise than my original answer. +1

Comment: You say it works with `--color`, but it does seem to (at least in Git 2.27.0). I tried `git log -10 --graph | git name-rev --stdin` and `git log --reverse -- t5526-fetch-submodules.sh  |git name-rev --stdin` and both outputs have no color (and the pager is disabled...)

Comment: OK. It does work with colors, and a pager if you want, but you have to convince Git. This works:
`git -c color.ui=always log -p --reverse -- t5526-fetch-submodules.sh  | git --paginate name-rev --stdin`. Note that `--paginate` can be shortened to `-p`.

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, older tag names are used as reference point rather than the point where the commit got merged.

That should be possible... soon (git 1.8.4 July 2013):

See [commit e00dd1e9485c50f202cc97dfae19d510e108b565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e00dd1e9485c50f202cc97dfae19d510e108b565):

```
describe: Add --first-parent option
```

> Only consider the first parent commit when walking the commit history.
>   This is useful if you only wish to match tags on your branch after a merge.

---

The [OP Lekensteyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427545/lekensteyn) comments it (`--first-parent`) isn't enough:

> `--first-parent` does not show the tag where it got merged too.
>   I just discovered that `--contains` can be used for that.
>   See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161796/6309) for an even better solution, [`git name-rev`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev).

Note: `git name-rev` dates back from [git0.99.9 (Oct. 2005!)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd321bcc51e95f644ac5335abe673afcbcaade62).

Comment: Note: I just tested it with "`git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0`" (latest version): it still works and display the tag.

Comment: I am using git 1.8.3.1. There are indeed tags for commits which are tagged, but other commits do not have such information.

Comment: @Lekensteyn so your question isn't about the absence of tag for a directory, but how to get a tag for *any* commit which hasn't one (as in `git describe`). Got it.

Comment: Correct, I have expanded my question with an example and why `git describe` does not satisfy my requirements at the moment.

Comment: @Lekensteyn maybe a future git describe --first-parent will be closer to what you are looking for? See my edited answer. I am firing up an Ubuntu virtual machine instance in order to compile a git as in latest master in order to test that.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I am looking for a generic solution for `git log` which does not necessarily have to use `git describe`. Consider the use case (add nearest tag to `git log`), not a possible implementation (how to fix `git describe`).

Comment: `--first-parent` does not show the tag where it got merged too. I just discovered that `--contains` can be used for that. See my answer for an even better solution, `git name-rev`. I am learning something new every day.